# Auto remove white background and add alpha channel to images?

Tags: media

I use Drupal 7.41 and created a "customers" view. This view get's nodes from the content-type (also called) "customers".

When I add images, some of them contain white background that conflicts with the sites gray-brick background; Is there a way to automatically make all uploaded images' white background removed and added an alpha channel so there won't be such a conflict?

Note: I can do that process manually with GIMP\Photoshop but looking for a module that does that automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the white background on the image itself? if yes, then you need to edit the image with Photoshop or some other image editing program and crop the image so there is no white.

Comment: actually you could use an image crop module, but you still have to select the area you want to upload. So it's not really automatic.

Comment: Yea I always do this things manually but I though there is something automatic... :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need something like https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions if this is in fact not a CSS border added to the image. I would definitely check that first but the above module does do some alpha blending and you can also run your own PHP/GD code during an image cache action so if they don't include it you can find code that does and run that code to perform the change.

You could also put a border around the image with CSS that would separate the image from the site background to solve something like that.

Comment: Looks great, I hope they'll port it to Drupal 8 soon :|